# The function $g(x) = (x − x_0)f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ for $f$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be continuous, but not necessarily differentiable, at $x_0$. Prove that the function $g$, defined by $g(x) = (x − x_0)f(x)$, is differentiable at $x_0$.

I can clearly see that using the product rule would be futile.

Comment: thank you all for your answers. I was looking at the wrong direction for a proof and never considered a simple chain of rearrangments.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

Just use the limit definition of the derivative.
Setting $g(x) = (x - x_0)f(x)$, note that $g(x_0) = 0$.
Then we have that

\begin{align*}
g'(x_0) &= \lim_{h\to 0} {\frac{g(x_0 + h) - g(x_0)}{h}} \\
        &= \lim_{h\to 0} {\frac{hf(x_0 + h)}{h}} \\
        &= \lim_{h\to 0} {f(x_0 + h)} = f(x_0)
\end{align*}

Since $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following. By definition of the derivative at $x_0$:

$$
g'(x_0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x_0 + h - x_0)f(x_0+h) - (x_0 - x_0)f(x_0)}{h}
$$

then, cancelling terms

$$
\begin{align}
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x_0 - x_0)f(x_0+h) + hf(x_0+h) - (x_0 - x_0)f(x_0)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{0f(x_0+h) + hf(x_0 +h) - 0f(x_0)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{hf(x_0+h)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} f(x_0+h)
\end{align}
$$

continuity gives you the final result.